# Change AtomicBoolean value in a runnable by different methods

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

MyRunnable has an atomic boolean which needs to be set to true by one method,
 another method to set to false in a multithreaded environment

```
   private final class MyRunnable<V> implements Runnable {

    private  AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean;

    public RunnableStudentFuture(AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean) {
        this.atomicBoolean = atomicBoolean;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!atomicBoolean.get()) {
            //spin
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this method the while loop in runnable will spin until the atomic boolean set to true

```
public void setToFalse() {
        ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        executorService.submit(new RunnableStudentFuture(atomicBoolean));
    }
```

Looking for a method like setToTrue to come out of the while loop. 
Something like signaling

```
public void setToTrue() {

    }
```

How can I achieve this in a multithreaded environment?

Is it possible to achieve this using CompletableFuture

Comment: What excactly is the your question? Why not use `AtomicBoolean#set`? Since `AtomicBoolean` is thread-safe, you can use it in different threads.

Comment: setToFalse() method to set the atomic boolean in runnable to false and setToTrue method to change atomic boolean to true

Comment: If you don't keep a reference to the RunnableStudentFuture OR its boolean, you can't do this^^

Comment: @azro can you show by example

Comment: You need to keep one variable, where is the main in all of this ?

Comment: I’m not sure whether you should try to implement multi-threaded logic if you struggle at such basic concepts already. There’s also a fundamental logic flaw, as you are describing a process with *at least three* different phases but try to control it with a boolean variable which can has only *two* different states.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to remember is that you will need to be able to (somehow) reference atomicBoolean from whichever thread you wish to set it's value from.  As this is a private member in the Runnable this means that you must:

1. expose a method on that runnable to set the value; and
2. keep a reference the instance of that runnable.

In the example below I have added methods to MyRunnable to enable setting the value.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean();

    public void setToFalse() {
        this.atomicBoolean.set(false);
    }

    public void setToTrue() {
        this.atomicBoolean.set(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.setToFalse();
        while (!atomicBoolean.get()) {
            System.out.println("running like mad");
            try {Thread.sleep(150L);} catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

To call the setToTrue method you will need to have a reference available to the instance in another thread.  So to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String... none) throws Exception {
    MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();

    System.out.println("starting runnable on different thread");
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    executorService.execute(myRunnable);

    System.out.println("wait on main thread");
    try {Thread.sleep(1000L);} catch (Exception e) {}

    System.out.println("calling set to true on main thread");
    myRunnable.setToTrue(); 
}
```

this method will execute the runnable in another thread then call setToTrue after a while in the original thread.  You would see output like this:

```
starting runnable on different thread
wait on main thread
running like mad
running like mad
running like mad
running like mad
running like mad
running like mad
running like mad
calling set to true on main thread
```